# In DotNetNuke, how do I get the admin email address?

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have a module that sends an email to a specified email address but I want to default the email recipient to the portal administrator.  How can I retrieve this information?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are in the context of a control inheriting from `PortalModuleBase`, `PortalSettings` is available as a property, so it would just look like

```
PortalSettings.Email
```

Answer (score 2):

```
' get the current portal
Dim portSettings As PortalSettings = PortalController.GetCurrentPortalSettings

' get email address
Dim email as string = portSettings.Email
```